# Converting DMS to decimal degrees, what precision?

Tags: latitude-longitude

I'm working on a piece of software that converts Lat & Long from DMS (`35° 19′ 20″ N`) to decimal degrees.

At the moment, the code creates number with 16 digits after the decimal point, which seems absurd.

Since we never have more than 2 digits for the arcseconds, would it be ok to round the decimal degrees we calculate? I'd like to round to the nearest 4th digit.

Comment: I guess 5 decimal places are enough if I only have integer seconds.